# API Response when an external API fails with 429 error

Tags: java, .net, rest, http

What is the API response that must be returned when an external API that the API calls returns 429? Should it return 500 as it is an internal server error for the API being called and should the API have some sort of circuit breaker to avoid overloading the external API or should it return 429 to ensure client does not overload the server with too many messages?

Comment: Agree with this ``should it return 429 to ensure client does not overload the server with too many messages``, since actually client is telling to backend to make a request to the third-party api. of course it's better to have rate limit on backend as well.

Comment: This is a functional question, not a technical one. Either answer could be correct depending on your business case. How does your front-end interact with those status codes?

Comment: Hi @Jorn, the frontend may be external systems and they are not in our control.

Comment: Thanks @sa-es-ir & Jorn. In general should the http status codes of external calls be cascaded back to the client by the API?

Comment: Mostly no, we should not expose those logic from external api but 429 is an exception, I think it is good to limit your client in the backend and 429 is a very common practice.

Comment: If you wanna put ratelimit on your api you can check my nuget package  , hope can help: https://github.com/sa-es-ir/DotNet.RateLimit